# Direct access to the internal fields of a CPython object

Tags: cython, reference-counting

To improve my understanding of Cython, I am trying to find a way to directly access the fields of the objects defined by CPython.

For example, I wrote the following code to access the `ob_item` field of a [`PyTupleObject`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a17f313e3958e825db9a83594c8471a984316536/Include/cpython/tupleobject.h#L11):

```
from cpython.ref cimport PyObject

cdef extern from "Python.h":
    ctypedef struct PyTupleObject:
        PyObject *ob_item[1]

cdef void f(PyTupleObject* pto):
    cdef unsigned i
    cdef object item

    for i in range(5):
        item = <object>pto.ob_item[i]
        print(item)

t = (1,2,3,4,5)
f(<PyTupleObject*>t)
```

Two questions here:

1. By doing so, did I mess with the object's reference counting, or is it ok?
2. How to call [`Py_SIZE`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/structures.html#c.Py_SIZE) on the `PyTupleObject` to retrieve the length of the tuple?

Comment: Tuple specific API https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/tuple.html#index-0.  `PyTuple_Size(pto)`?

Comment: Does python style indexing work in cython? `for item in pto: print(item)`.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, @hpaulj. Python-style indexing, as per your example, works for variables of the special type `object`. It will leverage the iterator protocol, which I try to bypass to access the underlying C data structure directly. `for item in pto` does not compile. Even if it did, I think that would try to iterate over a C-style array of `PyTupleObject`.

Comment: Your first suggestion, using `PyTuole_Size` works, but it does an unnecessary type check (https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bfc57d43d8766120ba0c8f3f6d7b2ac681a81d8a/Objects/tupleobject.c#L87-L96). For this "challenge", I would like to tackle directly at the lowest possible level.

Comment: Do you have any hints about the other part of the question regarding the Python object's reference counter? Do I need to use `Py_INCREF` or `Py_DECREF` (https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/refcounting.html), or is it ok right now since the C-style pointer remains valid for the whole `f()` function execution time?